# Polymorphic has_one built through accepts_nested_attributes_for is not setting polymorphic type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, spree, polymorphic-associations

*Note: While the project uses Spree Version 2.3, I am not currently of the belief that it is a Spree-specific problem. Though please correct me if I am wrong.*

The Spree framework has a model called [`Calculator`](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/2-3-stable/core/app/models/spree/calculator.rb) which looks like this:

```
module Spree
  class Calculator < Spree::Base
    belongs_to :calculable, polymorphic: true

    ...
  end
end
```

I am inheriting from this class to create my own calculator which simply looks like (which is little different than any other Spree [Calculator subclass](https://github.com/spree/spree/tree/2-3-stable/core/app/models/spree/calculator)):

```
module Spree
  class Calculator
    class PercentDiscountOnVariant < Calculator
      preference :percent, :decimal, default: 0

      ...
    end
  end
end
```

My model, called `ClientProduct` has a `has_one` relationship with `Calculator`, and can accept nested attributes for it, simply like so:

```
module Spree
  class ClientProduct < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :calculator, inverse_of: :calculable, foreign_key: "calculable_id", dependent: :destroy

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :calculator

    ...
   end
end
```

**The problem** is that when I create the `ClientProduct` (either a new record, or updating an existing), the `calculable_type` column in the `calculators` table remains null. **However**, the `calculable_id` IS populated correctly with the `ClientProduct`'s id.

The relevant portion of the parameter map is:

```
"client_product"=>{
    "variant_id"=>"300", 
    "client_id"=>"2", 
    "role_ids"=>["7"]
    "calculator_attributes"=> {
        "type"=>"Spree::Calculator::PercentDiscountOnVariant",
        "preferred_percent"=>"15"
    }
}
```

And the `ClientProduct` is created simply with `Spree::ClientProduct.create(client_product_params)`.

What would cause the polymorphic ID to be set correctly, while simultaneously leaving the polymorphic type column null?

*Minor sidenote: I am somewhat lying a bit for simplicity and brevity's sake regarding how the `ClientProduct` is built. Multiple `ClientProduct` rows are mass inserted, using combinations variant_ids and client_ids. However, the `calculator_attributes` are the same for each `ClientProduct` that is created, so I do not believe this particular setup changes anything. However, if anyone feels this might be relevant, let me know and I will provide the actual (though longer) code.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure if this is the cause, but you left out the polymorphic part in the other side of the relation ( the has one side )

```
has_one :calculator,
  inverse_of: :calculable,
  foreign_key: :calculable_id,
  dependent: :destroy,
  as: :calculable        #  <== this part
```

Comment: My goodness, that did the trick. So I think the core issue here is that wasn't clear on how the `as` option worked. I had expected that Rails would be able to figure out the type since it was being built as a nested object, but apparently not. And the answer to why the the ID was being correctly set was because it was behaving as a simple relationship due to the naming convention. Thank you for your help.